# Jquery long syntax is not working

Tags: jquery, animation, syntax

I had a div and I wanted it to slide down or up when something was clicked.
I was using the function slideToggle() like this:

```
$('.business').slideToggle(1500, 'easeOutBounce');
```

It works and sometimes its a bit choppy on firefox.
However when I tried using the following syntax it did not work?

```
$('.business').slideToggle({duration: 1500, easing: 'easeOutBounce'});
```

why? Arent they the same?

Comment: Apparently not.  I don't see your second version on the [documentation page](http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/).

Comment: @Sparky http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/#slideToggle-options -- the object syntax should work fine, as long as you have jQueryUI or an easing plugin installed to provide `easeOutBounce`. http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/u6t5y/

Comment: @Sparky ...except [he appears to be wrong](http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/#slideToggle-options). [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/u6t5y/)

Comment: @Blazemonger, yeah, I wasn't sure but figured you should see his answer.

Answer (score 3):

No, they are not the same. [`.slideToggle()` does not accept the object-argument syntax.](http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/)

Comment: According to your link, it does, since jQuery 1.0.... [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/u6t5y/)

Comment: @Blazemonger iiiiiiinteresting. The documentation page must have been wrong.